# My app slows down when background image is added in the drawable folder

Tags: android

I have read on this forum that the answer is to split the image in different resolutions and put it in different folders and the other way is to put the image in one folder without splitting it up so that android doesn't resize it.

My question is in which folder exactly do we put it on so it doesn't resize itself and shows as it is?

My res folder looks like this

[image]

Comment: in drawable folder you can add only if you are not want resize according your device

Comment: Have you added your background resource for multiple resolutions? If you add a large single resource file for your background it will take time to calculate and resize itself according to the screen size.

Comment: If you do not want resizing, then put the image in a folder called `drawable-nodpi`. But I would not recommend that, because then your background wouldn't be scalable.

Comment: @Vishalkumarsinghvi thx man, Sp4Rx yes i have added only single large image and thanks for the explanation it tells why app is slow,

Comment: @Fantomas as seen in the image i have no folder called drawable-nodpi. Do i need to create it manually? How to call the file in that folder since in the code as i know only how to call from drawable folder and not other ones.
Lets say I create a drawable-nodpi folder and place a single image then still the app slowdown will continue right? If yes I would rather learn the rescaling :(

Comment: Yes, you do have to create it. The documentation is quite clear about that. You don't "call" a drawable. You just use it - referring it by id, which is the same for all the drawable folders. Android takes care of extracting the resource from the appropriate folder. You need to read a bit of documentation for developing even the most basic app.

Comment: Roger that thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question with the image and the clarity.
You are asking how to avoid scaling. You can either use the drawable directory or the drawable-nodpi to avoid prescaling. Either one will work for you.

I made a document on this once for the UI team I was working with, so this document is a little specific to their request and that app, but it might help you.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gJjT-F5AU57TCAr5I18l0jAvNG5-vLUb/view?usp=sharing

For vector drawables just use "drawable" standard directory. Make sure you are not violating any of the unsupported tags such as gradients and linear tags or you will have issues.

Next the -24 -26, etc.. folders are used for version specific. For example, let's say you have one type of image for pre 24 Android, but a different type for post 24, you can use -24 for the post image, and all others will check standard folder for it. This sometimes happens when you use something bleeding edge that isn't supported back far enough for your app's minimum SDK. You are not likely to use this for images, I can't even think of a problem where this would arise in the image buckets, but it's there all the same.

For deciding what resolution you need for each bucket, there are a couple of options here. First you could simply do the math. Decide how many inches you want it to take up and determine how many pixels are needed to accomodate that size and label that MDPI, than scale from there using the multipliers. Another less mathematical solution would be to open a preview on Android select an MDPI device and start playing with width = 100px height = 100px and adjust until you like the size. Write that down, it is MDPI, and begin your scaling from there.

As for a rough estimate of pixels to size, you can see what an app icon looks like and see what Android uses for that below.

[image]

So even though each bucket has a different pixel by pixel resolution, they will be identical sized and pixels per inch resolution on all devices due to bucket placement.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

--I'll leave the below from the original answer in case it helps someone--

You may have gotten some bad information.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Android is a widely dispersed resolution and size market.
In order to accommodate this they allow for DP and Buckets.

There are buckets for languages, screensizes, orientation, and resolutions.

You are looking for resolution support.

> drawable-ldpi    -.75 multiplier on size (1dp = .75px)
>
> drawable-mdpi    -baseline 1dp = 1px
>
> drawable-hdpi    -1.5x multiplier on size (1dp = 1.5px
>
> drawable-xhdpi   -2x   multiplier on size (1dp = 2px
>
> drawable-xxhdpi  -3x   multiplier on size (1dp = 3px
>
> drawable-xxxhdpi -4x   mulipvlier on size (1dp = 4px

each bucket has a multiplier associated to help the image look the same approximate size on each device. So even though it is 1 inch by 1 inch on one mdpi phone with your 100px x 100px image (pseudo size, don't calculate it ;)

it will need to be 150px x 150px on the hdpi to have the same quality and resolution of pixels per inch.

Now if you put all your images in the drawable bucket. Android will just ignore the scaling of these and you end up with varying space consumption depending on the device which will be very inconsistent on how much space it takes up on each type of phone.

If you put all your images in the correct folder you will at least have better quality. For example, let's say you have maybe 750px x 750px image that is meant to fill up a 1 inch area. You would be better suited to put it in the XXHDPI folder or XXXHDPI folder so Android knows to scale it DOWN rather than UP. This will give you better resolution for each device resolution that it scales for.

However, this is still poor practice. You are relying on Android operating system which can be very slow and weak on many cheap devices to do your scaling for you. I would recommend using GIMP and scaling to each multiplier on your own, then putting it into the respective resolution buckets.

This way Android decides based on the device which bucket resolution image it needs which decreases the amount of scaling exponentially.

Now, if you have Vector Graphics that you have imported, those will end up in the drawable folder which tells Android to ignore the resolution, and just draw these as vector graphics. This is the best option in my opinion as you only need one set of images per image. Although, Vector graphics aren't quite as fast at loading as a JPG or PNG, but it keeps your package size down quite a bit and development maintenance is so much nicer.

Hope that helps.
Happy Coding.

Comment: Hi sam,
Thanks for the indepth answer.

I have few more questions please: (please look at attached pic for folder names)
1>
If I have a vector image then exactly which folder do I paste it in?
2>
Drawable,Drawable-v24, anydpiv-26 what are these folders for? If i am putting images as per the resolution in all folders(like hdpi,mdpi) then what to put in these 3 folders?
3>
hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi what resolution pic do I paste in these folder? i mean lets say in folder xhdpi what resolution it needs? and then for xxhdpi what resolution will it need?

Comment: sure too many questiuns to answer inline, I'll update my answer

Comment: Ok I added a link to a document you can download that will give you more info as well on the math of calculating sizes. StackOverflow doesn't let you attach files, so had to share on google drive.

Comment: Thanks for the file and the updated answer.
This has answered lots of my queries. Thanks & cheers.